# Call external stub from grpc test class

Tags: spring-boot, junit, grpc-java, cucumber-junit

I am trying to call the grpc service using stub (proto are present in the different jar file). But when I am trying to call that service I am getting **caused by io.grpc.statusruntimeexception unimplemented method not found**. The same is working fine in main class but not in test case.

DeviceGroupServiceImplBase deviceService = Mockito.mock(DeviceGroupServiceImplBase.class,
            AdditionalAnswers.delegatesTo(new DeviceGroupServiceImplBase() {
            }));

```
public void createInProcessServerAndChannel() throws IOException {
    // Generate a unique in-process server name.
    String serverName = InProcessServerBuilder.generateName();

    // Create a server, add service, start, and register for automatic graceful
    // shutdown.
    grpcCleanup.register(
            InProcessServerBuilder.forName(serverName).directExecutor().addService(deviceService).build().start());

    // Create a client channel and register for automatic graceful shutdown.
    ManagedChannel channel = grpcCleanup
            .register(InProcessChannelBuilder.forName(serverName).directExecutor().build());

    // Create a DeviceGroupServiceClient using the in-process channel;
    groupStub = DeviceGroupServiceGrpc.newBlockingStub(channel);
}

// Test case code
When("user calls getDevice with valid deviceUUID {string}", (String deviceUUID) -> {
    DeviceUuid request = DeviceUuid.newBuilder().setDeviceUuid(deviceUUID).build();
    DeviceGroup groupData = groupStub.getDeviceGroupByDeviceUuid(request);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to implement `getDeviceGroupByDeviceUuid`, by default it returns unimplemented status. you can verify if it is calling  `ServerCall#asyncUnimplementedUnaryCall`.

```
DeviceGroupServiceImplBase deviceService = 
  Mockito.mock(
    DeviceGroupServiceImplBase.class, 
    AdditionalAnswers.delegatesTo(
      new DeviceGroupServiceImplBase() {
        @Override
        public void getDeviceGroupByDeviceUuid(
            DeviceUuid request, StreamObserver<DeviceGroup> responseObserver) {
          // TODO: implement
        } 
      }));
```

Comment: this worked out but why it is calling actual stub in the method again, do i need to mock that as well?

Comment: `AdditionalAnswers.delegatesTo` option is make the mock call the real method of the passed object. this can be very useful if you want to use verify on a real object. if this was just mock it could work except you need to manually bind the service. (mock should be avoided if possible anyways)

Comment: // actual method
`public void getDevice(Device req, StreamObserver <Device> respObs) {
//some code logic
DeviceGroup deviceGroup = groupStub.getDeviceGroupByDeviceUuid(request);
}`

// Test case
`When("user calls getDevice", () -> {
 DeviceUuid request = DeviceUuid.newBuilder().setDeviceUuid(deviceUUID).build();
 groupData = mockGroupStub.getDeviceGroupByDeviceUuid(request);
 responseObserver = StreamRecorder.create();
        // This line is calling actual stub again
 deviceService.getDevice(request, responseObserver);
 responseObserver.awaitCompletion(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
});`

Comment: is that io.grpc.testing.StreamRecorder? just looking at the code, it shouldn't call the stub. maybe it is the next/previous line? it does look like it is calling the stub. if it does, you should implement that method. btw, you should not block the call (last line).

Comment: I have implemented the way suggested above for testing but the actual main stub is in some other jar file whose server is not up. Ideally, actual stub should not be called right?

Comment: in general mocking stub is not a good idea and fake implementation is a good alternative. the problem here is partial implementation of the Service, so i would say nothing really wrong here. if you don't use verify on the mock, you can probably just use the fake impl.

Comment: I did the fake impl and its working fine but when I call getDevice() from test case, in getDevice actual stub is present on reaching that line i m getting server unavailable. So I am bit confused even after doing fake impl on reaching the actual stub why it is looking for actual server.

Comment: that sounds strange, can you check stacktrace? just looking at partial snippet made me confused (i don't use cucumber).

Comment: yes i m using cucumber, is there any other way to do that?